# Not sure what is happening in my while loop

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, scanf

I am totally new to programming and learning the basics.  I can not figure out what is happening with my output.  Please help.

Here is my code (using xcode on mac)

```
// C Programing
// Program 6C: Basic While loop Example 2
// In this program we will demonstrate the use of basic while loop

#include <stdio.h> 


int main()
{

int values = 1;
int count = 1;
int value_array[values];

printf("Please enter how many values you have:  ");
scanf("%d", &values);

printf("You entered %d values.\n",values);

while (count <= values)
{
printf("Please enter your %d\n value:   ", count);
scanf("%d", &value_array[count]);
count++;
}

count = 1;

while (count <= values)
{
    printf("For the %d value you entered %d.\n", count, value_array[count]);
    count++;
}

return 0;
}
```

> here is my output ( not sure why I am getting 31 for some of my entered values )

Please enter how many values you have:  10
You entered 10 values.
Please enter your 1
 value:   1
Please enter your 2
 value:   2
Please enter your 3
 value:   3
Please enter your 4
 value:   4
Please enter your 5
 value:   5
Please enter your 6
 value:   6
Please enter your 7
 value:   7
Please enter your 8
 value:   8
Please enter your 9
 value:   9
Please enter your 10
 value:   10

For the 1 value you entered 1.
For the 2 value you entered 2.
For the 3 value you entered 3.
For the 4 value you entered 4.
For the 5 value you entered 5.
For the 6 value you entered 31.
For the 7 value you entered 1.
For the 8 value you entered 31
For the 9 value you entered 9.
For the 10 value you entered 10.
Program ended with exit code: 0

think I did everything right

Comment: You should specify what you are not able to figure out in `while` loop ?

Answer (score 5):

You're going off the end of your array.  This:

```
int values = 1;
int value_array[values];
```

creates a single-element array, but you then treat it as a 10-element array (or more).  This invokes "undefined behaviour", which basically means all bets are off and the program might do anything at all.

Comment: +1 add to this the indexing is wrong (1-based when it should be zero-based) and its a recipe for UB.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your help.
I see where I declared int values and set it to 1 was incorrect.
My second mistake was declaring the array before asking the user to enter the array size.





    int values;
    int count = 1;
  
    printf("Please enter how many values you have:  ");
    scanf("%d", &values);
    
    printf("You entered %d values.\n",values);
    
    int value_array[values];
    
    while (count <= values)
    {
        printf("Please enter your %d\n value:   ", count);
        scanf("%d", &value_array[count]);
        count++;
    }

Answer (score 3):

"think I did everything right" - believe the computer; doubt yourself first, last and always. If the behavior isn't what you expect, then you need to examine your expectations.

I see a values_array declared, but I don't see where you allocated any memory for it using malloc.

When you declare the array, values is set to 1.  The user then decides that they want to enter 10 values, but the array declaration is unchanged.  What happens when you try to allocate beyond the first array element?  Seems wrong.

It's been too long since I last wrote C, but I'd check that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
   {
   int values = 1;
   int count = 1;
   int value_array[values];
```

The flaw in the question code includes the above line.  At this point, `value_array` is an array of `1` element.  Specifically, the only valid index is `value_array[0]`.

Even though `values` may be changed in the following lines, the number of elements in `value_array` will be unchanged.  It is 'fixed' with a single element.

Obviously the intent is to have `value_array` reference a variable number of elements, as specified by the user.  This is possible by changing the above declaration of `value_array` to the following:

```
   int *value_array = NULL;

   printf("Please enter how many values you have:  ");
   scanf("%d", &values);
```

Now that the user has specified the number of elements for the array, memory can be assigned to the array 'dynamically' by adding the following line:

```
   value_array = malloc(values * sizeof(*value_array));
```

If the above line was successful, the `value_array` is ready for use.  However, what if `malloc()` fails (due to there being no memory available, etc.)?  If so, instead of pointing to a block of allocated memory, `value_array` will point to NULL.  It is important to validate that `malloc()` was successful.  I would suggest adding some lines (next) as follows:

```
   if(NULL == value_array)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed.\n");
      exit(1);
      }

printf("You entered %d values.\n",values);

while (count <= values)
  {
   printf("Please enter your %d\n value:   ", count);
   scanf("%d", &value_array[count]);
   count++;
   }

count = 1;

while (count <= values)
   {
       printf("For the %d value you entered %d.\n", count, value_array[count]);
       count++;
   }
```

Now that the memory backing `value_array` is no longer needed, it is always proper to release it back to the system:

```
   if(value_array)
      free(value_array);

   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used ur code it doest give me such a error
compiled it using codeblocks ide

i have been initialing my array as u did since a year now never got an error

according to me ur code is just fine

Comment: plz let user below reputation point 10 to post photos as in this i wanted to add screenshot of my outcome but couldn't do so